# How to redirect if the page is empty

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a problem in Cake 3 whereby I want to have a controller check to see if its associated table is empty. If it is, it should forward to /add rather than list the empty index page.

Right now the url `/introduction/index` shows an empty index page, I'd like users to be automatically redirected to `/introduction/add` so they can get on with adding an entry.

If the id column of the DB has an entry, they should remain at the index. Hope that makes sense.

I tried the following in introductionController.php:

```
public function emptycheck()
{
    $introduction = $this->Introduction->get($id);
    if ($id = null) {
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
    } else {
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

It does nothing, but I took some solace in the fact it didn't produce errors. How can I check if there is a record and redirect if there isn't?

Comment: I just have to mention this: Shouldnt you check $id for null before doing the introduction->get($id); And also, you should probably use $id == null, as a single "=" is assignment, while "==" is comparison. I havent used Cake myself, but thats just my 5 cents.

Comment: And those 5 cents would be correct. I'll get there eventually...

Comment: The method in the question won't do anything because nothing calls it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CakePhp there is the isEmpty() method to use.

```
$results = $this->Introduction->find('all');
if ($results->isEmpty()) {
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
} else {
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

There is the related documentation [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#checking-if-a-query-or-resultset-is-empty)

A different issue I see here is, that the configuration doesn't follow CakePhp conventions, about the use of plural and singular form of names. These conventions are [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)

Comment: Thanks Igor. As you have alluded to, I am still getting to grips with CakePhp. Last time I did any coding was ten years ago...

Answer (score 1):

This worked in the controller, appending the index() function like so:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->set('introduction', $this->paginate($this->Introduction));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['introduction']);
    $introduction = $this->Introduction->find()->all();
    if ($introduction->isEmpty()) {
        return $this->redirect(
            ['controller' => 'Introduction', 'action' => 'add']
        );
    } else {
        return $this->redirect('/introduction/index');
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.